# Tkinter frame deleting

Tags: python, tkinter

Alright so here's my problem. I am currently in the process of making a GUI for a discord.js bot ( I know how to interact between python and node ) but my problem is that I have a "Password" 4 digit pin and what's supposed to happen is:

Whenever you enter the four digit pin it should delete the frame, entry, text, etc (Unpack/destroy()) it but it's not doing that. It is, however, deleting the text and text entry point but not the actual frame its self.

```
>##Importing Functions (eg, npm modules but in python)
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint
import sys
##Root core
root = Tk()

##Developers pin-codes

JaredP = "9119"


##End

##Hash Check + Main core functions
def check_pin():
    if code.get() == JaredP:

        ##Main Core (After auth is done forget packs at bottom)




        #End of main


##End of check


##Frames for the main core function(Auth)

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(6,6,12,12))
frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100)
checkt = ttk.Label(content, text="Hello, please enter your 4 digit pin.", padding=(12,12,12,12))
namelbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Access Code")
code = ttk.Entry(content)
submit = ttk.Button(content, text="Submit", width=10, command=check_pin)


##End of frames

##Design##

root.title("TEX")
root.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

##End##

##Packing for main body

content.pack()
checkt.pack()

namelbl.pack()
code.pack()
submit.pack()

root.mainloop()
##End of packing
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to minimize your code but you should include the part where you are actually trying to _remove_ the frame so we can see what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To remove you can use, `YOUR_FRAME.pack_forget()` or `YOUR_GRID.grid_forget()` depending on whether the frame was packed or grid.

if you aren't going to use it again (independently if it's a frame or grid) `YOUR_ELEMENT.destroy()`